# Map in react-native-webview, How to zoom?

Tags: react-native, webview, maps, zooming

I put a map in a webview using react-native-webview this way :

```
<WebView
   geolocationEnabled={true}
      source={{
         uri:
              "https://www.blablabla",
          }}
      originWhitelist={[
            "https://www.blavla.org",
            "https://www.blabla.com",
          ]}
   style={{ marginHorizontal: 0, backgroundColor: "transparent" }}
/>
```

Giving me this :

[image]

But as you see, it's not really clear, I'd like to zoom to have a better reading of the map (it's too small this way we can't read anything). How can I do that please ?

Thanks for any help !!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site has page width set in meta already

So you will need to override that with injectedJavaScript

```
injectedJavaScript={`const meta = document.createElement('meta'); 
meta.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5, maximum- 
scale=0.5, user-scalable=0'); meta.setAttribute('name', 'viewport'); 
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta); `}
scalesPageToFit={false}
```